# Python Tkinter grid method not working - Python 3.4.3

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

I have used the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title('Test')
window.geometry('500x500')
TestButton = Button(text='TEST')
TestButton.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

But this code still puts my button in row 0, column 0! Help!

Comment: rows and columns that have nothing in them have a size of zero.

Comment: Thank you! That explains it!